# Can't activate WordPress plugin -- no settings page

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am trying to install the JM Twitter Cards plugin and am having a problem I suspect is not specific to this plugin.

I clicked the "activate" link for this plugin in my local dev site, my staging site and my production site.  In my local dev site, the plugin installed successfully.  But in my staging and production site, the "Deactivate" link appears when the plugins list reloads, but there is no "Settings" link, and if I point my browser to the URL where the settings page should appear...

wp-admin/admin.php?page=jm_tc

...I see "Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page."

I've tried deactivating the plugin and re-activating, but I still do not have a settings page for this plugin in my staging or production site.

Answer (score 0):

It caused by permissions. Yours might not be sufficient to view settings for the plugin. This specific plugin requires `manage_options` capability which is available to `Administrator` and `Super administrator` roles.
Refer to [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) doc to learn more about roles and capabilities

Comment: The account I use is in the administrator role.

Comment: I logged in with the super user ("admin") and still do not see the settings link, nor do I see the JM Twitter Cards item, in the sidebar menu.  I have confirmed that in the file system, the plugin files have the same permissions as my other plugins.